# should I use a CDN like cloud flare for heroku backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, server-side, netlify

I'm creating a website using netlify (static html, css, javascript) as my front end and heroku (node.js) as my backend
since netlify itself has CDN I don't think there's any necessity to use cloud flare

However, as far as I know the Heroku backend runs only on one server at one place
so if I use a CDN like cloud flare for heroku will it make multiple "copies" of my server and distribute them? or am I understanding the concept incorrectly?

I'm a bit new to all this sorry in advance if I don't make sense

Comment: What is "Cloudflare" and "Netlify"? Both are companies, not products.

Comment: I'm using their products I don't really know how else to describe it @JonasWilms

Comment: If you already use Netlify, I don't think Cloudflare is needed. Heroku will host your servers (backend) in a single location. Something like fly.io makes copies of your server, but the hard part is your database.